# SingalR message not sent to the client without any errors

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a hub class:

```
 public class OrderHub : Hub
    {
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            Clients.Caller.orderMessage("New connection");
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public static void SendOrderMessage(string msg)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<OrderHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.orderMessage(msg);
        }
    }
```

An event handler that is calling the static method:

```
    public async Task Handle(IOrderProcessedEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // Here we could write a code with SignalR to notify the page about successful process

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            //orderHub.OrderMessage("Order processed successfully");
            OrderHub.SendOrderMessage("Order processed successfully");
        }
    }
```

And a simple JavaScript code that should log the message (this is a very simplified example):

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            var hub = $.connection.orderHub;
            console.log("hub initiated");

            hub.orderMessage = function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);


            };

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>
```

There's something missing, since the function is never called, not from OnConnected, not from the static method.

`console.log("hub initiated");` line gets printed, and the hub variable is valid, but the actual `function(msg)` never gets called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "client":

```
hub.client.orderMessage = function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);


        };
```